# Brother DCP-J140W Driver in ubuntu 13.04 32 bit

Tags: 13.04, drivers, printing, brother

I need to install my printer "Brother DCP-J140W" driver in ubuntu 13.04 "32 bit" where I can find it & how to install it

Comment: You find instructions and drivers here: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J140W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Brother Solution Center](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J140W).

They provide the drivers for printing and scanning and detailled instructions on setup.
Please read the instructions carefully. Then, printing and scanning as a regular user even through wireless works nicely.